# Unable to "yum install" RPM package from local repository (Oracle Linux)

Tags: yum, rpm, repository, oracle-linux

I am working on Oracle Linux and trying to create a local repository. I managed to create a .repo entry which points to a directory in my system. The directory contains an RPM package.

But when I use the command "yum repolist", it shows the repository but lists the status of the repository to be zero. But the directory does contain RPM packages.

[image: status=0]

Here's the .repo file.

```
[rhel_repo]
baseurl=file:///rhel_gnu_repo
enabled=1
```

I tried running **`createrepo`** on the directory again and I am getting the following output.

```
[root@ttnetwork /]# createrepo /rhel_gnu_repo/
Spawning worker 0 with 2 pkgs
Worker 0: Error: Could not open local rpm file: /rhel_gnu_repo//avidemux-2.6.12-5.fc24.i686.rpm: RPM Error opening Package
Worker 0: Error: Could not open local rpm file: /rhel_gnu_repo//avidemux.rpm: RPM Error opening Package
Workers Finished
Gathering worker results
Saving Primary metadata
Saving file lists metadata
Saving other metadata
Generating sqlite DBs
Sqlite DBs complete
```

These are the contents of the folder.
[image: contents]

Comment: (1) [please do not post images of text](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), (2) how the file in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` looks?

Comment: it's the console picture. and i added the file too

Comment: Can you post the contents of the folder? Did you run `createrepo` in that folder?

Comment: Yes I just tried again and I realize I am getting another error. i am going to post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question had a bunch of problems. I was able to solve them and get the local repository working. I will post the solution to these problems here.

1. The status of the repolist should not be zero. It should be equal to the number of RPM packages available. This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/307213/yum-repolist-shows-status-0/307214#307214) shows exactly how to solve this problem.
2. The createrepo command was giving errors because the RPM package was corrupted. It mustn't have been downloaded properly. Use the yum "download-only" extension to make sure you download a proper RPM package.
3. Make sure you have only RPM packages in your repo directory. The directories I had in that directory were also causing problems. This should solve your issues regarding local repositories.

Comment: thanks, the 1. was usefull !

Answer (score 1):

In our case, we got the same error due to rpm file that was corrupted.

Fix was to re-download the rpm, then rerun the create repo command.

Answer (score 0):

The question shows that createrepo failed to open the RPM files, so it is not surprising that there is nothing in the repodata directory.

The apparent problem is the trailing slash on this command:

```
createrepo /rhel_gnu_repo/
```

which is confusing `createrepo`.  You probably meant

```
createrepo /rhel_gnu_repo
```

Comment: Still getting the same error even without the trailing slash

Comment: With a `#` prompt, you're probably running as `root`, so the other possibility is that you're trying to use RPMs on a machine with an older version `rpm` which does not support the compression type, etc.

Comment: But I have worked with rpm packages before, installed some for instance. Is there a way to test this? Should I try using some other RPMs? And what do you mean by compression type?

Comment: A few years ago, the RPM program switched from gzip-compression to xz-compression.   See [this](http://www.rpm.org/wiki/Releases/4.7.0) for example.

Comment: I will try to determine if this is the case and get back to you afterwards.