# yum repolist shows status 0

Tags: rpm, repository, oracle-linux

I am working on Oracle Linux. I am trying to create a local repository and install RPM packages from there using yum install. I created a local repository and added a `.repo` file in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. I run the following commands.

```
yum clean all
yum update
yum repolist
```

[image: status = 0]

Why isn't it detecting the RPM package in the directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for the `repolist` showing the status zero. Apparently, it is because of the rest of the `.repo` files in the `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory. Just rename the files to an extension other than `.repo` or move them to another directory leaving on the one you need behind. After that, run the following:

```
yum clean all
yum update
yum repolist
```

The status should now be fixed.

[image: fixed]

[**Here**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21972347) is another description for the same solution.

**However, please be aware that doing this will remove those other repositories from your list and you won't be able to download packages from them. To use them again, simply put them back with the proper extension and they'll work fine.**

Comment: You shouldn't rename the other repos - you should just do the `yum clean` bit. Removing other repos will have undesirable side effects.

Comment: @John It didn't work that way. I tried. You're welcome to try.

Comment: in this folders /etc/yum/ when run : 
'ls' command the results :
protected.d  repos.d  vars  version-groups.conf  yum.conf  yum-daily.yum  yum-weekly.yum   what about this? in debian

Comment: @sabertabatabaeeyazdi It looks like its a different directory you mentioned. The one you should be looking for is /etc/yum.repos.d/

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler solution to this. Just do

```
sudo touch /etc/yum.repos.d/<your_repo_file>
yum repolist
```

You should see your repo is refreshed. I don't know why it is like this, my assumption is that yum doesn't bother to refresh a repo that hasn't been updated.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution here did not work for me.
[This](https://low-orbit.net/how-to-install-yum-on-ubuntu) does not work either.
After seeing [this](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/16/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Managing_Yum_Repositories.html), the proposed solution here looks wrong, indeed.

The correct approach to adding repos to yum should be:

1. `sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo myrepo`
2. `sudo nano myrepo.repo`

Edit `baseUrl` parameter providing a valid repo url. A working repo sample looks like:

```
[myrepo]
name=repoDemo
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/
enabled=1
```

3. `sudo yum-config-manager --enable myrepo.repo`

Running `yum repolist` will not show 0 repos anymore, rather your repoDemo instead.

Answer (score 0):

It may happen if you are incorrectly adding spaces in the repo name:

```
[Base Old Repo] #<--- WRONG
Name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Instead:

```
[BaseOldRepo] #<--- CORRECT
Name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem on Cento 7. When I try to add an new repo ... 
The command `yum repolist` show zero status for all the latest repo .. 
I don't know what, exactly, the problem is, but I think that the system needs specific time to check and update the repolist database